# submit spark-task with keycloak credential on behalf of a user

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, keycloak, kerberos

I have a Hadoop cluster with YARN as the resource manager, which is secured with Kerberos authentication. Kerberos is backed by Active Directory LDAP.

On the other hand, I have a server application that also requires authentication. The authentication mechanism implemented for this application is Keycloak integrated with Kerberos. According to the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#credential-delegation), if both the clients and Keycloak are properly configured, once a user is authenticated, my application should receive a `gss delegation credential` via an OIDC token. Now, the question is, can I submit a Spark application using this `gss delegation credential` on the aforementioned Hadoop cluster on behalf of an authenticated user?